# Running Python Mathplotlib through Java Interface

Tags: java, python

I am trying to run a python mathplotlib through a JAVA GUI interface. The plot input i.e. the list is user give. Therefore the runtime and exec commands aren't working as they need an already written code. 
Is there anyway I can take user input from Java GUI and use it to plot in python(mathplotlib) and display the pic (It is fine if the image is not displayed on the GUI but occurs as in separate window)